# Missing input snakemake expand error mixes inputs

Tags: python, snakemake

My snakemake workflow prints it mixes the inputs.

> MissingInputException in line 21 of /scratch/blumenscheitc/workplace_5z/diaa_nn_fasta/Snakefile:
> Missing input files for rule prokka:
> genome/real_name_hypo_200707_20-07797_19-03322_S19.fasta.fasta

I have no idea why sadly.
The code is below.
I wrote a lot of workflows like that but this one doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

```
import sys
import os

shell.executable('/bin/bash')

IDS, = glob_wildcards('genome/{sample}.fasta')

rule all:
    input:
        expand('results/proteome_DIA_input_{sample}.fasta', sample=IDS),
        expand('temp/real_name_hypo_{sample}.fasta', sample=IDS),
        expand('temp/real_name_hypo_{sample}.tsv', sample=IDS),
        expand('temp/names_hypo_{sample}.data', sample=IDS),
        expand('temp/hypo_count_{sample}.fasta', sample=IDS),
        expand('temp/non_hypo_{sample}.fasta', sample=IDS),
        expand('temp/hypo_{sample}.fasta', sample=IDS),
        expand('temp/{sample}.fasta', sample=IDS),
        expand('proteomes/{sample}.gbk', sample=IDS),
        expand('temp/{sample}', sample=IDS),

rule prokka:
    input:
        'genome/{sample}.fasta',
    output:
        'temp/{sample}',
    shell:
        '''
        prokka {input} -prefix proteome --addgenes --compliant --outdir {output} --cpu 40
        '''

rule prokka_rename:
    input:
        'temp/{sample}',
    output:
        'proteomes/{sample}.gbk',
    shell:
        '''
        cp '{input}/proteome.gbk' '{output}'
        '''

rule gbk2fasta:
    input:
        'proteomes/{sample}.gbk',
    output:
        'temp/{sample}.fasta',
    shell:
        '''
        python scripts/gbk2fa_prot.py {input} {output}
        '''

rule hypo_fasta:
    input:
        'temp/{sample}.fasta',
    output:
        'temp/hypo_{sample}.fasta',
    shell:
        '''
        seqkit grep -w 0 -rnip 'hypothetical' {input} > {output}
        '''

rule non_hypo_fasta:
    input:
        'temp/{sample}.fasta',
    output:
        'temp/non_hypo_{sample}.fasta',
    shell:
        '''
        cat {input} | grep -v '^>' | grep '^.' | tr -d '[:blank:]' | cat >( echo '>seq_name') - > {output}
        '''

rule hypo_fasta_count:
    input:
        'temp/hypo_{sample}.fasta',
    output:
        'temp/hypo_count_{sample}.fasta',
    shell:
        """
        seqkit replace -p .+ -r "hypothetical_protein_{{nr}}" {input} > {output}
        """

rule diamond_hypo:
    input:
        'temp/hypo_count_{sample}.fasta',
    output:
        'temp/blast_hypo_{sample}.data',
    shell:
        '''
        diamond blastp -b 20 --threads 40 --max-target-seqs 1 --db "/home/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/wissdaten/ZBS6_Orbitrap/xxxxxxxx/Databases/uni_bac.dmnd" -f 6 sseqid full_qseq --query {input} --out {output}
        '''

rule hypo_header:
    input:
        'temp/names_hypo_{sample}.data',
    output:
        'temp/real_name_hypo_{sample}.tsv',
    script:'scripts/hypo_header.R'

rule hypo_tsv2fasta:
    input:
        'temp/real_name_hypo_{sample}.tsv',
    output:
        'temp/real_name_hypo_{sample}.fasta',
    shell:
        '''
        seqkit tab2fx {input} > {output}
        '''

rule combine_fasta:
    input:
        I1='temp/real_name_hypo_{sample}.fasta',
        I2='temp/non_hypo_{sample}.fasta',
    output:
        'results/proteome_DIA_input_{sample}.fasta',
    shell:
        '''
        cat {input.I2} {input.I1} > {output}
        '''
```

Comment: If the prokka rule is looking for "genome/real_name_hypo_200707_20-07797_19-03322_S19.fasta.fasta" as an input, that means it's trying to create the output "temp/real_name_hypo_200707_20-07797_19-03322_S19.fasta". That indicates that (1) you should probably redefine your prokka output pattern to be more specific and (2) snakemake is either failing to find the correct way to create "temp/real_name_hypo_200707_20-07797_19-03322_S19.fasta" or incorrectly trying to make it.

Comment: Also, you should use the directory() wrapper for the prokka output to tell snakemake that prokka is going to create a directory: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#directories-as-outputs

Comment: I changed the output of prokka to be more specific now proteome_{sample} thos solved the output problem.